# django, phpmyadmin and mysql?

Tags: mysql, django, windows-7, phpmyadmin, xampp

I would like to start using Django with MYSQL, instead of sqlite all the time, however my only experience using MSQL is through XAMPP, manipulating databases through phpmyadmin. I would really like to keep this gui interaction with mysql and not have to do everything through command line.

Can you start and manage a MYSQL database using xampp/phpmyadmin, and then use django for the web development side only using Django'sn development server?

Or do you have to always start new databases through command line, and if so how is it done, bearing in mind I only ever use mysql through xampp/phpmyadmin?

I know how to link and manage a database through django, I just dont know how to start a mysql one through it, and I dont really want to have to loose the mysql gui that comes with xampp/phpmyadmin. all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can definitely manage Mysql through the XAMPP interface. Try setting the DB_HOST in settings.py to "localhost". If it doesn't work, try "127.0.0.1". This is typically caused by the python-mysql module expecting the mysql unix socket to be in another place than it is. Actually, I'm unsure if the mysql server uses a unix socket on Windows. Anyway, one of both should work :)
You can use the credentials you use to login with phpmyAdmin also for Django. Many consider it bad style to use root for non-administration tasks (and I agree), but for starters and on your development machine it isn't too big of an issue.
phpMyAdmin should work out of the box with your django-managed databases.

My database settings.py block for mysql looks something like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'DBNAME',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'USER',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': 'PASSWORD',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

This is for django 1.2 and above. Replace DBNAME, USER and PASSWORD with the respective values and try '127.0.0.1' as HOST if you run into problems. Obviously, you'd need to run 'manage.py syncdb' as you did with sqlite before you can use it.

Comment: I want to do the same thing, but having issue... 
- Did you install mysqlclient or MySQL-python?
This is the error I already having. Now, after database configuration, if I run server, I face that, although I have php myadmin is running.
https://imgur.com/9UeQzfT


Now, I tried to do 'manage.py syncdb' also. It returns same issue-
https://imgur.com/WpuKv1X


FYI, I am using mac and xampp. Any luck for me @kevinRead ?

Answer (score 4):

I'd highly recommend checking out [postgresql](http://www.postgresql.org/)! It comes with a Sqlserver-Management-System-like Database Browser that runs on your desktop, rather than a web based front end. Now you don't need to worry about configuring PHP alongside Django. Postgresql will probably be harder to install than MySql on XAMPP, but I believe that you can get a lot out of doing so.

Postgresql is also a lot better (IMO) than MySQL, and is the recommended database to use with Django according to a lot of the people close to Django.

That said, I currently use Oracle, so you probably shouldn't listen to me. :)

Comment: I second this, looking into MySQl-alternatives is often a good idea. MySQL is widespread and pretty fast, but that doesn't mean it's good in every respect. Exploring other DBMS gives more insight into pros and cons of MySQL, and you'll know when to choose which DBMS.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I didn't think of using postgresql with django even though Ive used it before with geodjango for spatial data. I guess I'm just too comfortable with phpmyadmin because I use that so often but this is a good solution, and since its recommended ill try using it for some time. cheers.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily manage your databases with phpMyAdmin. All what Django needs is permission and access information for your database. Once those are set up (granting permissions in phpMyAdmin and adding the access information in Django's settings.py), you would issue a `manage.py syncdb` for example and you're done.