# Trying to run python manage.py migrate on a djangoFramework project but receiving errors

Tags: python, mysql, django

Following a tutorial on youtube on how to set up and use the DjangoFramework. Tried running python manage.py migrate but I ran into this error and I'm unable to figure out a solution to it. Using mysqlclient and running on a virtual environment and on MACOS

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")

I don't know if this would be the issue, but I created a database on using the myphpadmin on http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/. localhost/phpmyadmin does not work.

The code for DATABASES in settings.py is as follows :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'djangoproject',
        'USER' :  'root',
        'PASSWORD' : 'rootpassword',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT' : '' ,
    }
}
```

Comment: did you update your settings.py?

Comment: edited the post. does updating settings.py mean putting values like i shown in the DATABASES ?

Comment: port is `3306` .

Comment: @Stack Tried that but it still gave the same error

Comment: did you create a database named `djangoproject` in mysql

Comment: @Stack yes i did it using phpmyadmin

Comment: check this answer ==> https://stackoverflow.com/a/4915878/8150371

Comment: @Stack I have looked into that and tried changing the HOST to 127.0.0.1 but it still gave me the same error.

Comment: Did you update the port, check the root password, its not authenticating

Comment: use mysql shell to connect using the root username and password

Comment: @Stack How would i check root password?

Comment: Pertaining to this, I think the mysql on my DjangoProject is not connected to the database on my local host. Tried using the mysql shell to connect but the password used is the one of my laptop's user password instead of the designated password in the code. Also, it has no databases in it

Answer (score 1):

If you are connecting with phpmyadmin by default no password set.
And also write port number.

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
 'NAME': 'djangoproject',
 'USER' :  'root',
 'PASSWORD' : '',
 'HOST': 'localhost',
 'PORT' : '3306' ,
}
```

[Change password of phpmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OxHC.jpg)

Comment: Tried this. Gave me the same error with (using password :NO) instead

Comment: @bernardang go to phpmyadmin  dashboard click the User accounts tab then check User name 'root' and Host 'localhost' then Edit privileges of this account. Then change password of this account.

Comment: Was I supposed to change it to what I put it as in the DATABASES code ?I did that and now I am getting Access Denied error.
 "phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server."

Comment: I have actually gotten it to work. by changing the settings on XAMPP. However, I still cant get phpmyadmin to work on localhost/phpmyadmin or localhost:8000/phpmyadmin where the server on my django app is run on.Any fix to this?

Comment: [Access denied error solution.  ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482371/fix-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-for-phpmyadmin)

Comment: When you run your server it give you server running link.                               Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.                                                  And phpmyadmin link is                                                     http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

Comment: localhost/phpmyadmin returns me :
This site can be reached. localhost refused to connect.

Comment: @bernardang Apache and MySQL is  running correctly ?

Comment: Yes it is. At least it shows that it's green on the XAMPP. Anyway, I am back to my previous issue. I realized that I ran the migration with the default sqlite3 provided by django that's why it worked. I am still unable to run python manage.py migrate with the mysql. I am still getting the same error. I have a feeling this has something to do with XAMPP being on a different port than my Django server.